# Links dont work (beginner html css only)

Tags: html, css

I've had a look through some questions I thought were similar to mine but it turns out even the beginner questions are advanced for me!

For some reason my links in the header and footer work, but not in the side bar or the main body, could someone please explain to me why and how i can fix it?
I've opened the html without the css and it works fine then, but i dont know how my css would make a link invalid :S

Code is here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gppbmP

Im "pretty" sure its the css thats messing things up so ive pasted that down there, but the codepen has the html too :)

(i am aware that it is super basic, but it is my first try and everyone has to start somewhere! :))

```
    body {
  font-family: "Helvetica";
  background: #DCDCDC;
}

header a {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.side a {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: gray;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.product a {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: gray;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}
  .product p {
    font-size: 12px;
  color: gray;
    text-align: center;
  } 
footer a {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: gray;
  text-decoration: none;
}
body a:hover {
  color: #FF0066;
}

.nav1 {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  top: 15px;
  left:20px;
}

.nav2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 47px;
  right: 70px;
  float: right;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Satisfy', cursive;
  font-size: 48px;
  position: relative;
  left: 420px;
}

header {
  background-image: url("http://www.hugohd.com/wp-content/uploads/Pink-Beach-Sunset-Wallpaper-Android-Wallpaper-hugohd.com_.jpeg");
  margin: 30px;
}

.product {
  background: white;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  left: -32px;
  height: 350px;
  padding: 30px;
}

.product img {
  height: 200px;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.side {
  margin: 30px;
  float: left;
  background-color: white;
  height: 800px;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  top: -29px;
  text-align: center;
}

.side ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

footer ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

footer ul li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 80px;
}

footer {
  position: relative;
  bottom: -40px;
  right: 100px;
}
```

Thanks in advance! x

Edit: Thank you for helping, everyone! it now works :) x

Comment: What do you mean by the side bar and main body links dont work?

Comment: I just mean that they arent clickable, and they dont turn pink like the links in the header and footer when you hover over them

Answer (score 7):

**Update**

What follows below may be of use if you are unsure how to set up anchor tags (some seem to be wrong) but see Tasos K's solution above (and voters look at his solution as well).

**Original Answer**

You seem to be missing `http://` at the start of your `href=`:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">google</a>
```

^^ that's the correct way of doing it but sometimes you have:

```
<a href="www.google.com">google</a>
```

When you leave out `http://` the browser thinks that the link is relative to the html page that it is trying to display. If you look at where those links try to take you they will be something like `http://www.example.com/www.google.com`.

That's actually a handy thing to use though because it means that media like javascript, css and images that are on your website don't need to be referenced with a full url. You can just use:

```
<img src="/images/background.png">
```

(instead of)

```
<img src="http://www.example.com/images/example.png">
```

Similarly with links, you can reference other pages on *your* site with:

```
<a href="/myOtherPage.html">Page 2</a>
```

Comment: That might not be the solution to the problem because the header and footer links work but others dont

Comment: It is a correct observation but it is not what the OP asks. Apparently she put only `www.google.com` in a hurry to make the codepen. The issue is that the links at the menu on the left are not clickable.

Comment: Very true, I see what you mean.

Answer (score 4):

You are positioning your `<footer>` with `position:relative;` and it goes over the side menu. You can see it clearly if you add a background-color:

```
footer {
    background-color:#DEDEDE;
}
```

You can see it [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WvvbJZ) in a demo. Depending on what you want to do, a solution to fix this can vary.

To fix the issue with your current layout, just set the `z-index` property to a value, e.g. 1. See [demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pJJvOV) here

```
.side {
    z-index: 1;
}
.container {
    position:relative; 
    z-index:1;
}
```

My suggestion is to reconsider your layout to avoid similar issues in the future.

Comment: Ja, I don't think `z-index` is the solution. Rethinking the layout is a much better idea.

Comment: @jcuenod it wokrs, I added a link from codepen for anyone to see

Answer (score 0):

adding this to your CSS file will make the links clickable

```
.product {
  z-index:1000;
}
```

Working demo with functional product links [here](http://codepen.io/user501254/pen/RPPNBr).

Answer (score 0):

@Sarah, i dont have exact know how , why? but if you rename your class from side to side1 or something else and then change the css to same as side1 or something it works fine.

Again i am not sure what could be the reason side is not working. And request you not to grade down if you dont accept.